# How to create different fluorescent colors using household items

Tags: water

This is a request:
I wanted to create fluorescent liquids that have different colors.

I'm going to dye my flowers in different fluorescent colors and I'd need a recipe for fluorescent colors that aren't too toxic.

Please bare in mind that the injection of the liquid can only happen by spraying or watering with the liquid.

The liquid needs to be able to handle being Waterdown by tap water.

I'd recommend using household items to make this more helpful to the average day user. Also any color will do but, the most wanted Colors are:

- List item

  - Blue
  - Green
  - Red
  - Yellow

Comment: Welcome to chemistry.stackexchange!  This is an interesting question.  May I suggest that you edit your question to include a description of the research you have already done on the topic?  For example, what documents have you already read?  If you put that into the question, folks trying to answer it won't waste your time by directing you to reference materials that you have already seen.

Comment: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/41858/how-to-create-different-fluorescent-colors-using-household-items?s=1|0.5338

Answer (score 3):

If you dismantle highlighter pens, you can find the felt material inside. This material contains fluorescent chemicals, such as pyranine. This felt like material is usually encased in a plastic film, remove the film and soak the felt in water.

If you use too much water then it may become too dilute and you may start to encounter an issue with the ink/water mixture sticking to the flower.

- Are you using a black light to view the fluorescent colour?

it might be worth trying to cut the stems and keep the flowers in the ink containing water. Then as they absorb the water they will absorb the fluorescent ink as well and may take on some of the colour (and viewable under black light).

Answer (score 2):

You might try some [light-sticks](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00B1LHCRG) for fluorescent chemical. Some of these chemicals are non-colored or pale  in visible light, but are *brightly* fluorescent under long-wave UV.

Note that though those I use are labeled "non flammable [sic] and non toxic [sic]... ingredients will not cause injury to the eye... do not drink or ingest," **they do contain easily broken glass containers with a "[luciferase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luciferase)".** Use caution with any experiment.